# Kitchen sprayer only uses half the water, how to fix?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, kitchens

I have a Moen kitchen faucet with separate sprayer. When I use the sprayer, it only cuts the main water flow by about half and sprays with the rest. Every other sprayer I've used will transfer all of the flow to the sprayer, cutting off the main faucet while in use.

What can I do to fix this? Do I have some strange model where this is by design? Is it time to buy a new kitchen faucet?

Comment: Almost every kitchen sprayer I've ever used did exactly what you described.

Comment: Will the diverter just pull out or is it threaded?

Comment: @Travismay I replaced the faucet years ago... Sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like it is a problem with the diverter. It could be clogged, rusted, or even damaged, and as such, may either need to be cleaned (soaking in vinegar may help), or outright replaced.

There are a couple types that Moen seems to use, so which one depends on your model. There is a collar-type vale:

[image]

And there is another type with a smaller inner valve:

[image]

You'll have to open the faucet to get at it (how you do this again depends on the model), and then pull out the diverter with pliers.